# Saving a repetitive search with variable in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I commonly find myself running this "entire solution" search with regular expressions:

diag.*###

where ### is replaced with a 3-digit number. Is there are good way to save this in Visual Studio 2012 without investing too much time in an add-in? My understanding is that Macros have been removed in this version.

Comment: Not an answer, but in ReSharper, you can save searches on semantic patterns. In fact, when searching for an identifier, you can specify a regular expression that the identifier must match.

Comment: You can use Visual Commander, very similar to built-in macros: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d